# Para que serve o incremento em um ponteiro?

Tags: c, ponteiro, memória

Dado:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int x = 1;
    x++;
    int *y = &x;
    y = y + 1;
    printf("%d\n",x );
}
```

A saída é 2.

Nesse caso gostaria de saber se a seguinte interpretação é correta: `y = y + 1;` apenas modifica o endereço, ou seja, acresce de 1 que significa 4 posições em relação a x, porém o valor de x não se altera, mantendo-se conforme a linha `x++;`.

Se essa afirmação estiver correta, a que mudança se refere a linha `y= y + 1;`? Ou seja, qual seria sua serventia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu entendimento está correto, o que está sendo feito com `y` é mudar o local que ele aponta, ele vai apontar para o próximo endereço de memória, que vai ter lixo deixado na memória.

Nesse seu exemplo a expressão `y = y + 1` não tem serventia, a não ser o descrito acima, pegar lixo da memória.

Em um outro contexto onde poderia ter uma sequência de inteiros, provavelmente inicializados, seria útil para pegar o próximo item da sequência. Obviamente essa sequência precisaria ter uma memória reservada em algum lugar, estática ou dinamicamente, caso contrário só pegaria lixo, e pior, poderia mudar algo importante para a aplicação ali.

Eu fiz um código para demonstrar como funciona, mas note que é praticamente uma coincidência que dê certo. Nada na linguagem garante que vá acontecer o que verá executando nesse exemplo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 1;
    x++;
    int *y = &x;
    y++;
    printf("%d, %d\n", x, *y);
    int z = 5;
    printf("%d, %d\n", z, *y);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/dhOmk6). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/enmtjxjw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/Arithmetic2.c).

Primeiro eu pego o lixo, depois eu inicializo uma nova variável ali e em seguida eu pego o valor naquele endereço. Isso dá certo porque a memória não deixa de ser uma sequência de dados sem um critério estabelecido. Nesse caso específico esse sequência é uma [pilha de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

Em C você cuida do acesso à memória na mão. Não tome cuidado e muita coisa pode sair errada.